# Evaluating content of liferay-ui:message in liferay-ui:input-editor

Tags: localization, internationalization, ckeditor, liferay

I want to use **liferay-ui:input-editor** in order to place content, but when I want to have content using the **liferay-ui:message** tag, I don't know how to do it, since it's generating **html** content and the **liferay-ui:message** is evaluated in server.
I thought about writing an **i18n** custom plugin for the **CKEditor** that will get the proper content once I "OK" it, but before I dive in to that, I wanted to check first if that is the only solution.
BTW - I know about the **liferay-ui:input-localized**, but for my purposes I need to use that message tag only.

Thank you :)